# PSQL - Refuses to use the -U argument

Tags: postgresql, macos, terminal, psql

I'm trying to connect to a AWS PSQL server. I ran the following

```
psql -h mbandtweet.xxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
 -U postgres
```

When I run it, I get a prompt that says : 'Password for user anant: '.
Now anant is the name of my local user on my computer. I think it's trying to login with the local machine's username and then failing as it's getting an authentication error.

The error is:

```
port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "anant"
zsh: command not found: -U
(base) anant@Anants-MacBook-Air Assignment 1 %
```

When I type psql --help, I can see that the default user is 'anant'. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, just changing the order of the arguments fixed it.

```
psql  -U <username> -h xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com
```

This fixed it

Comment: No what fixed it was not having `-U` on a separate line, the error being"`zsh: command not found: -U`. On other words the shell `zsh` was seeing `-U postgres` as being a new separate command.